# mutate with lag in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I  have some R using mutate and lag. I want to duplicate this in Pandas. This is the data

Edited: to include the need for the group by and index

```
        Name       Date_x  
  0   American   2009-10-31
  1   American   2009-09-22
  2   Zydaco     2009-09-26
  3   American   2009-04-17
  4   American   2009-02-18
  5   American   2009-02-03
  6   American   2009-01-16
  7   Catalina   2009-09-02
  8   Zydaco     2009-08-29
  9   Zydaco     2009-08-15
 10   Zydaco     2009-06-26
 11   Zydaco     2009-10-27
 12   Zydaco     2009-10-13
 13   Zydaco     2009-04-04
```

This is the R code

```
test<-  test %.%                      #need dplyr %.% 
        group_by(name) %.%
        mutate(Date_y = lag(Date_x, 1))
```

Edited to reflect that this approach also fails
This is the Python code that I made that fails to duplicate the output that I am trying to achieve

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
test1 = test
test1['Rank'] = test1['Rank'] + 1
test1 = test1.drop('Name', 1)
test2 = pd.merge(test, test1, on='Rank')
```

This is an attempt to create the output using .shift.  Which seems to be much more efficient. But the output is not correct.

Edited; To demonstrate the issue

```
test['Date_y'] = test.groupby(['Name'])['Date_x'].shift(-1)
test.sort(['Name', 'Date_x'], ascending=[1, 0])
                 Name     Date_x      Date_y
         American    2009-10-31  2009-09-22
         American    2009-09-22  2009-04-17
         American    2009-04-17  2009-02-18
         American    2009-02-18  2009-02-03
         American    2009-02-03  2009-01-16
         American    2009-01-16  NaN
         Catalina    2009-09-02  NaN
         Zydaco      2009-10-27  2009-10-13
         Zydaco      2009-10-13  2009-04-04
         Zydaco      2009-09-26  2009-08-29
         Zydaco      2009-08-29  2009-08-15
         Zydaco      2009-08-15  2009-06-26
         Zydaco      2009-06-26  2009-10-27
         Zydaco      2009-04-04  NaN
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? I would like to use .shift if it worked. 
Or is there a better way?

This is the line that is not correcct

```
          Zydaco         2009-06-26  2009-10-27
```

This reproduces the error.

```
df = pd.Series        (['American','American','Zydaco','American','American','American','American','Catalina',
'Zydaco','Zydaco','Zydaco','Zydaco','Zydaco','Zydaco'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = ['names']
df['date_x'] = pd.Series(['2009-10-31','2009-09-22','2009-09-26','2009-04-17','2009-02-18',' 2009-02-        03','2009-01-16','2009-09-02','2009-08-29','2009-08-15',' 2009-06-26',' 2009-10-27','2009-10-13','2009-       04-04'])
df['date_y'] = df.groupby(['names'])['date_x'].shift(-1)
mask = df['names'] == "Zydaco"
df = df[mask]
df['date_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_x'])
df.groupby('date_x').apply(lambda d: d.sort()).reset_index('date_x',drop=True)
```

date_x is in order from the date farthest out to the most recent date. It seems shift doesn't use the order of the dates, instead it uses the index order to shift.

```
       names date_x     date_y
13   Zydaco 2009-04-04   NaN
10   Zydaco 2009-06-26   2009-10-27
9    Zydaco 2009-08-15   2009-06-26
8    Zydaco 2009-08-29   2009-08-15
2    Zydaco 2009-09-26   2009-08-29
12   Zydaco 2009-10-13   2009- 04-04
11   Zydaco 2009-10-27   2009-10-13
```

Comment: Your dataframe has a `Date_x` column, but in the groupby you use `Date`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not sorted to begin with, so it will be shifted in this unordered order. If you want to shift it in a sorted manner, first sort it before the groupby. Eg:

```
In [49]: test['Date_y'] = test.sort('Date_x', ascending=False).groupby(['Name'])'Date_x'].shift(-1)

In [50]: test.sort(['Name', 'Date_x'], ascending=[1, 0])
Out[50]:
        Name      Date_x      Date_y
i
0   American  2009-10-31  2009-09-22
1   American  2009-09-22  2009-04-17
3   American  2009-04-17  2009-02-18
4   American  2009-02-18  2009-02-03
5   American  2009-02-03  2009-01-16
6   American  2009-01-16         NaN
7   Catalina  2009-09-02         NaN
11    Zydaco  2009-10-27  2009-10-13
12    Zydaco  2009-10-13  2009-09-26
2     Zydaco  2009-09-26  2009-08-29
8     Zydaco  2009-08-29  2009-08-15
9     Zydaco  2009-08-15  2009-06-26
10    Zydaco  2009-06-26  2009-04-04
13    Zydaco  2009-04-04         NaN
```

---

I don't know how you exactly got the result (a fully runnable example would help there), but if I run something similar, I get:

```
In [26]: s="""Name       Date_x   Rank
   ....: American    2009-10-31  6
   ....: American    2009-09-22  5
   ....: American    2009-04-17  4
   ....: American    2009-02-18  3
   ....: American    2009-02-03  2
   ....: American    2009-01-16  1
   ....: Catalina    2009-09-02  1
   ....: Zydaco      2009-10-27  7
   ....: Zydaco      2009-10-13  6
   ....: Zydaco      2009-09-26  5
   ....: Zydaco      2009-08-29  4
   ....: Zydaco      2009-08-15  3
   ....: Zydaco      2009-06-26  2
   ....: Zydaco      2009-04-04  1"""

In [27]: test = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)

In [29]: test['Date_y'] = test.groupby(['Name'])['Date_x'].shift(-1)

In [30]: test
Out[30]:
        Name      Date_x  Rank      Date_y
0   American  2009-10-31     6  2009-09-22
1   American  2009-09-22     5  2009-04-17
2   American  2009-04-17     4  2009-02-18
3   American  2009-02-18     3  2009-02-03
4   American  2009-02-03     2  2009-01-16
5   American  2009-01-16     1         NaN
6   Catalina  2009-09-02     1         NaN
7     Zydaco  2009-10-27     7  2009-10-13
8     Zydaco  2009-10-13     6  2009-09-26
9     Zydaco  2009-09-26     5  2009-08-29
10    Zydaco  2009-08-29     4  2009-08-15
11    Zydaco  2009-08-15     3  2009-06-26
12    Zydaco  2009-06-26     2  2009-04-04
13    Zydaco  2009-04-04     1         NaN
```

Is this what you want? Or what is wrong with it?

Note that you don't need the groupby in this case as there is only one name in the `Name` column, but I suppose that is because you simplified the example.

Comment: I edited the question to include additional names so that the groupby is necessary. I think that the problem is demonstrated now.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? I updated my version above with your new data. Is there something wrong with the output I get? (it seems correct to me) I you run that, do you get something else?

Comment: My Pandas is '0.14.1'. What you get is correct. When I run it I get something else. See what I get at the end of my question.

Comment: I added the index to my test data. This must be the problem.

Comment: If I run *my* code with 0.14.1, I get exactly the same as I posted above (run with 0.15.1). Please provide a fully reproducible example that shows the error.

Comment: OK, you now changed the data. But the data is not sorted to begin with! If you want to shift it in a sorted manner, first sort it before the groupby. See my updated answer

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. Thanks.